# Utilizar métodos de un objeto creado en otra ventana

Tags: java, poo

Lo que se pretende es que al iniciar el `Principal`, se abra la `Ventana1` y el usuario introduzca su nombre, y al presionar el botón, inicialice un objeto `Persona1`, y se asigne el nombre a la propiedad `nombre`. Después, que la `Ventana2` pase a ser visible (Hasta aquí he llegado).

- Lo que quiero ahora, es poder hacer que no sea visible la `Ventana1` al    presionar el botón (creo que no puedo porque he creado el objeto en la clase `Principal`, y no me deja hacer `v1.setVisible(false)`. ¿Cómo lo podría hacer?
- También me gustaría, el objeto `Persona1` creado al presionar el botón,    poder utilizarlo en `Ventana2`, es decir, poder hacer por ejemplo un `persona1.getNombre()` desde esa clase. ¿Habría alguna manera? Así también podría solucionar la primera pregunta (que quería usar el objeto `v1` creado en `Principal` desde la clase `Ventana1`).

Tengo el siguiente código:

Clase `Ventana1`:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Ventana1 extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField cajaNombre;
    private Persona p1;
    private Ventana2 v;

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Ventana1(Ventana2 v) {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        cajaNombre = new JTextField();
        cajaNombre.setBounds(29, 24, 376, 22);
        contentPane.add(cajaNombre);
        cajaNombre.setColumns(10);

        JButton botonContinuar = new JButton("Continuar");
        //LISTENER
        botonContinuar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //Acción a realizar al presionar el botón

                //Creamos una persona p1
                p1=new Persona();

                //Asignamos el nombre de la caja de texto a la persona
                p1.setNombre(cajaNombre.getText()); 

                v.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        botonContinuar.setBounds(161, 59, 97, 25);
        contentPane.add(botonContinuar);
    }
}
```

Clase `Ventana2`:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Ventana2 extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JLabel etiquetaNombre;

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Ventana2() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        etiquetaNombre = new JLabel("New label");
        etiquetaNombre.setBounds(157, 31, 56, 16);
        contentPane.add(etiquetaNombre);
    }
}
```

Clase `Persona`:

```
public class Persona {
    //Propiedades
    private String nombre;

    //Métodos
    public void setNombre(String s){
        nombre = s;
    }
    public String getNombre(){
        return nombre;
    }

    //Constructor
    public Persona() {
        System.out.println("Creada una persona");
    }
}
```

Clase `Principal`:

```
public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Creamos las ventanas que vamos a utilizar
        Ventana2 v2 = new Ventana2();

        //Pasamos como parametro v2 para interactuar entre ellas
        Ventana1 v1 = new Ventana1(v2);

        //Hacemos visible la primera
        v1.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿v1 y v2 se llaman desde la misma aplicación y sólo hay que leer los de v1 en v2?

Comment: Exactamente igual que lo harías con cualquier otros objetos; pasas la instancia compartida como parámetro mediánte un `setter` o en el constructor, ya sea de una ventana a otra o bien desde un objeto que mantenga referencias a las dos ventanas...

Comment: @pacomaral Si por a dos ventanas te refieres a dos instancias de `JFrame`, entonces estamos ante un problema de diseño. Deberían ser un `JFrame` más un `JDialog`. Por otra parte, puedes compartir la misma instancia de algún objecto utilizando un *setter*, ya sea en `v1` o en `v2`, dependiendo de cuál sea ventana principal o secundaria.

Comment: Pues lo pasas como parámetro en el constructor de la nueva ventana.

Comment: EDITADA CON CÓDIGO. Creo que ahora es mucho más entendible lo que quiero hacer

Answer (score 1):

la primera pregunta para cerrar ese ventana  puedes usar el metodo dispose(); que tiene el JFrame dices lo siguiente

```
this.dispose();
```

la segunda pregunta puedes hacer que el objeto sea estatico es decir lo tienes en la Ventana1

```
static Persona miPersona;
```

para accedes a el atraves de la ventana 2 puedes decir

```
Ventana1.miPersona;
```

asi puedes acceder desde la ventana2 a la ventana1